# Using python selenium the error element cannot be located comes up when i stop script otherwise script will never return error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, py-telegram-bot-api

using python selenium on the carecredit.com/apply page after you select proffesion and click enter you are prompted to put last 4 of your ssn and phone number but the element is never found. or maybe the element does not exist?

```
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver3.get('https://www.carecredit.com/apply/')
#care credit profession
carecategory = Select(driver3.find_element(By.ID, 'profession-apply'))
carecategory.select_by_visible_text('Other')
#care credit get started
carestarted = driver3.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="ApplyForm"]/input[28]')
driver3.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", carestarted)
#care credit last 4 of ssn
carelast4 = driver3.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pfLandinglast4SSN"]')
carelast4.send_keys(ssn3)
#care credit mobile
carephone1 = driver3.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'pfLandingMobileNo')
carephone1.send_keys(phone)
#care credit continue
carecontinue = driver3.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="payfoneSubmitbtn"]')
driver3.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", carecontinue)
driver3.implicitly_wait(10)
```

this is the code i am using ive tried both xpath and id for the phone and ssn neither returned success
when i stop the script from running i get a whole bunch of errors returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 671, in <module>
    carelast4 = driver3.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pfLandinglast4SSN"]')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 860, in find_elements
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"] or []
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 438, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 290, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 311, in _request
    response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\dee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1376, in getresponse
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 953, in close
    def close(self):

KeyboardInterrupt
```

maybe the element i am trying to find does not exist any help greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668648/python-selenium-after-i-do-click-a-new-url-is-opened-in-my-project-but-then-n